# Angular 2 Jasmine Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, angular-routing

I'm creating a unit test for my Navbar Component and I'm getting an error:

> Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

**Navbar Component TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavActiveService } from '../../../services/navactive.service';
import { GlobalEventsManager } from '../../../services/GlobalEventsManager';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-navbar',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls:['navbar.component.css'],
  providers: [NavActiveService]
})
export class NavComponent {
  showNavBar: boolean = true;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private navactiveservice:NavActiveService,
              private globalEventsManager: GlobalEventsManager){

    this.globalEventsManager.showNavBar.subscribe((mode:boolean)=>{
      this.showNavBar = mode;
    });

  }

}
```

**Navbar Component Spec**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';    
import { NavComponent } from './navbar.component';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export function main() {
    describe('Navbar component', () => {

        let de: DebugElement;
        let comp: NavComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavComponent>;
        let router: Router;

        // preparing module for testing
        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [NavComponent],
            }).compileComponents().then(() => {

                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavComponent);
                comp = fixture.componentInstance;
                de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('p'));

            });
        }));


        it('should create component', () => expect(comp).toBeDefined());


/*        it('should have expected <p> text', () => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
            const h1 = de.nativeElement;
            expect(h1.innerText).toMatch(" ");
        });*/


    });
}
```

I realize that I need to add router as a spy, but if I add it as a SpyObj and declare it as a provider I get the same error.

Is there a better way for me to add fix this error?

**EDIT: Working Unit Test**

Built this unit test based on the answer:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async  } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NavComponent } from './navbar.component';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterLinkStubDirective, RouterOutletStubComponent } from '../../../../test/router-stubs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GlobalEventsManager } from '../../../services/GlobalEventsManager';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared.module';


export function main() {
    let comp: NavComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavComponent>;
    let mockRouter:any;
    class MockRouter {
        //noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedFunction
        navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate');
    }

    describe('Navbar Componenet', () => {

        beforeEach( async(() => {
            mockRouter = new MockRouter();
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [ SharedModule ]
            })

            // Get rid of app's Router configuration otherwise many failures.
            // Doing so removes Router declarations; add the Router stubs
                .overrideModule(SharedModule, {
                    remove: {
                        imports: [ RouterModule ],

                    },
                    add: {
                        declarations: [ RouterLinkStubDirective, RouterOutletStubComponent ],
                        providers: [ { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter }, GlobalEventsManager ],
                    }
                })

                .compileComponents()

                .then(() => {
                    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavComponent);
                    comp    = fixture.componentInstance;
                });
        }));

        tests();
    });


        function tests() {
            let links: RouterLinkStubDirective[];
            let linkDes: DebugElement[];

            beforeEach(() => {
                // trigger initial data binding
                fixture.detectChanges();

                // find DebugElements with an attached RouterLinkStubDirective
                linkDes = fixture.debugElement
                    .queryAll(By.directive(RouterLinkStubDirective));

                // get the attached link directive instances using the DebugElement injectors
                links = linkDes
                    .map(de => de.injector.get(RouterLinkStubDirective) as RouterLinkStubDirective);
            });

            it('can instantiate it', () => {
                expect(comp).not.toBeNull();
            });

            it('can get RouterLinks from template', () => {
                expect(links.length).toBe(5, 'should have 5 links');
                expect(links[0].linkParams).toBe( '/', '1st link should go to Home');
                expect(links[1].linkParams).toBe('/', '2nd link should go to Home');
expect(links[2].linkParams).toBe('/upload', '3rd link should go to Upload');
                expect(links[3].linkParams).toBe('/about', '4th link should to to About');
                expect(links[4].linkParams).toBe('/login', '5th link should go to Logout');
            });

            it('can click Home link in template', () => {
                const uploadLinkDe = linkDes[1];
                const uploadLink = links[1];

                expect(uploadLink.navigatedTo).toBeNull('link should not have navigated yet');

                uploadLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
                fixture.detectChanges();

                expect(uploadLink.navigatedTo).toBe('/');
            });


            it('can click upload link in template', () => {
                const uploadLinkDe = linkDes[2];
                const uploadLink = links[2];

                expect(uploadLink.navigatedTo).toBeNull('link should not have navigated yet');

                uploadLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
                fixture.detectChanges();

                expect(uploadLink.navigatedTo).toBe('/upload');
            });

            it('can click about link in template', () => {
                const uploadLinkDe = linkDes[3];
                const uploadLink = links[3];

                expect(uploadLink.navigatedTo).toBeNull('link should not have navigated yet');

                uploadLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
                fixture.detectChanges();

                expect(uploadLink.navigatedTo).toBe('/about');
            });

            it('can click logout link in template', () => {
                const uploadLinkDe = linkDes[4];
                const uploadLink = links[4];

                expect(uploadLink.navigatedTo).toBeNull('link should not have navigated yet');

                uploadLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
                fixture.detectChanges();

                expect(uploadLink.navigatedTo).toBe('/login');
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: which Angular version you are using ? because `providers` option isn't there on component metadata in Angular 2 final released version

Comment: I'm using 2.1.0. Do you mean provide is no longer an option for unit tests? I believe you still use providers in modules. I'm using the angular seed and they're still in the example: https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/blob/master/src/client/app/home/home.module.ts

Comment: I was talking about your `NavComponent`'s `providers` option

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The [Angular Testing docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) address this by using `RouterLinkDirectiveStub` and `RouterOutletStubComponent` so that `routerLink` *is* a known property of `<a>`.

Basically it says that using `RouterOutletStubComponent` is a safe way to test `routerLinks` without all the complications and errors of using the real `RouterOutlet`. Your project needs to know it exists so it doesn't throw errors but it doesn't need to actually do anything in this case.

The `RouterLinkDirectiveStub` enables you to click on `<a>` links with `routerLink` directive and get just enough information to test that it is being clicked (navigatedTo) and going to the correct route (linkParams). Any more functionality than that and you really aren't testing your component in isolation any more.

Take a look at their [Tests Demo](https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/testing/specs.stackblitz.html) in `app/app.component.spec.ts`. Grab the `testing/router-link-directive-stub.ts` and add to your project. Then you will inject the 2 stubbed items into your TestBed declarations.

Comment: Added my working unit test, hopefully can help someone else if they're struggling. Thanks again!

Comment: i don't understand why these stubs don't ship in /master

Comment: I ran into an issue with these stubs, ts-lint complains that the selector should be prefixed with app: The selector of the directive "RouterLinkStubDirective" should have prefix "app"

Comment: 404 on the demo link :-(

Comment: I believe you can get the router stubs from this link now; they changed the documentation:
https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/testing/bag-specs.eplnkr

Comment: The link will work when you go to the Docs page and then click the link... Somehow its not linkable directly

Comment: demo link not found

Answer (score 60):

Just import **RouterTestingModule** in `TestBed.configureTestingModule` of your **components spec.ts** file

Eg:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';


TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule],
  declarations: [ ComponentHeaderComponent ]
})
```

Comment: This is my preferred way for unit tests as it allows you to spy on the routes without actually changing the route. https://angular.io/api/router/testing/RouterTestingModule#description

Comment: no offense but i think this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want only isolated test and DO NOT CARE about template,you can add **NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA**. This tells Angular not to show error if it encounters any unknown attribute or element in HTML

Eg:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ ComponentHeaderComponent ],
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})
```