# angular 4 ng test Failed: Template parse errors: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:

Tags: angular, jasmine

Failed: Template parse errors:
'router-outlet' is not a known element:

1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. `If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("[ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/***.html@0:0`

> angular 4 ng test Failed: Template parse errors: 'router-outlet' is not a known element

[image]

Comment: Did you import the `RouterModule`? Please provide the code that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes a have import the RouterModule. but is not working

Comment: Please show the code

Comment: @HemantVishwakarma were you able to solve your issue?

Answer (score 9):

**Try this**:
In (app.component.spec.ts)
Add **imports:[RouterTestingModule],** into your TestBed from @angular/router/testing, like this:

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing'; // <= here
...
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule], // <= and here
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,

        ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
});
```

**OR**
Sometime, it's just one line of code that will fix this problem.
Add: 
**exports: `[ RouterModule ],`** 
into the @NgModule of your routing.module.ts and it'll fix this.
This is my **routing.module.ts**, I have to add it manually because when I do **ng g m routing**, the Angular CLI didn't add this.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = 
[
    // Your paths to the components
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),

  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [ RouterModule ], // <= Add this line 
})
export class ComponentRoutingModule { }
```

Import the **RoutingModule** into your **app.module.ts**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if the answer to this works in your scenario
[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751138/angular-2-jasmine-cant-bind-to-routerlink-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of)

Important... Open the [NG Test Guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing) and then click the link for *"Tests"*. This will open the test sample.
Copy the files *"Testing\activated-route-stub.ts"* and *"Testing\router-link-directive-stub.ts"* in your project (better in a separate folder).

Now move to "app.component.spec.ts" and notice how these two files are added as declarations for each test module... Also notice the *@Component* declaration for the router-option, without it, the stub won't work.

The spec also tells how to use the stubs to test out the router links actually..

Do the same and enjoy... Let me know if it helps :)  If there are any errors, make sure you are importing all items

(My spec file as follows)

> import { RouterLinkDirectiveStub } from '../router-stubs.module';
>
> @Component({ selector: 'router-outlet', template: '' })
>
> class RouterOutletStubComponent { }

...

> declarations: [
> MyOwnComponent,
> RouterLinkDirectiveStub, ***here we add our component and stub***
> RouterOutletStubComponent
> ],